# write specified lines to a new file

Tags: java, nmea

I have a nmea message. I want to write out into an other file only `$GPGSV` lines. Here is my code, which now write boolean (true, false) for each lines. How can I write the values of lines?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       File inputFile = new File("proba.txt");
       File tempFile = new File("kiir.txt");

       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();

    writer.write(currentLine.startsWith("$GPGSV") + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
```

Comment: use an `if` around the write (or ask the original author to add one for you)

Comment: Some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Give some sample input and output lines so everyone can understand what you are missing in your code ?

Answer (score 1):

`startsWith()` returns a boolean, so the way you use it, it will simply print `true` or `false` to file. Try this instead

```
if(trimmedLine.startsWith("$GPGSV"){
    writer.write(trimmedLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Edit: used `trimmedLine` in place of `currentLine`. I assume that was what you wanted to use.